# Are Convolution Kernels Predefined or Does a CNN Define them During Training

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, convolution, conv-neural-network

I understand how convolution kernels work and their function in neural networks. However, I'm not sure if in the typical CNN you would predefine what the convolutional kernel is or if that is something that the CNN "figures out." For example, in making a CNN would you simple define some 5x5 convolution kernel like this:

```
kernel = [[ 0,  1, -2,  1,  0]
          [ 0,  2, -1,  2,  1]
          [ 1,  0,  1,  0,  0]
          [-1, -1,  0, -3, -1]
          [-3, -2,  0,  1,  1]]
```

Or would you simply tell the CNN to find a 5x5 kernel and after training it will have come up with a good 5x5 kernel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For CNN the kernels are trained during the optimization procedure, so each number in the matrix is a free parameter, adjusted according to partial derivative of the loss considered with respect to this particular variable.

So to answer

> Or would you simply tell the CNN to find a 5x5 kernel and after training it will have come up with a good 5x5 kernel?

You would tell the model to use K kernels of given size, with given spacing, maybe in multiple layers, followed by other operations, and it will find all the kernels on its own.

Comment: So what is this paper describing? http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P03-1005

Comment: "kernel" has many meanings in both mathematics and computer science. Convolutional kernel in neural nets (CNN) are different objects from convolutional kernels for kernel methods (described in this paper). In kernel methods, kernels are dot product in Reproducing Hilbert Spaces, and are rarely learnable (at most their mixing coefficients can be learned).